# var_prefix= not working as one would hope

Tags: templates, playa, variable, nesting

OK revamped question: now it displays all the right stuff but it doesn't interact with the tabs and stacks them all in a static display. straight forward EE code works fine. Once i insert the prefix to get the last breakdown locations names however it does not

http://niwot.colorado.edu/index.php/location (straight forward EE code) (PS if you click on the pills some don't have placeholder text)

http://niwot.colorado.edu/index.php/location/test_location2 (with the prefix code but it repeats and doesn't interact with tabs. some how things are not set correctly. tried quite few variations with no success any suggestions?)

```
{exp:playa:children field="3rd_order_under" limit="25" sort="asc" var_prefix="thirdorder"}
             <li {if count == '1'}class="active"{/if} id="pillTab{url_title}Tab">
               <div class="row">                                     
                 <div class="twelve columns"> 
                   {thirdorder:summary_3rd_order}<br />

                   {thirdorder:exp:playa:children field="4th_order_under_3rd_order" sort="asc" var_prefix="fourthorder"}
                     {fourthorder:title}
                   {/thirdorder:exp:playa:children}

                 </div>
               </div>
             </li>
           {/exp:playa:children}
```

note: please see playa doc on children for reference

Comment: I think the prefix is only for variables and tags, not loops.  I might be wrong though

Comment: If summary_3rd_order is through the outer playa loop, it should be prefixed as well: {thirdorder:summary_3rd_order}

Comment: From your example page it's tough to tell what's not working. From what I can see you're getting output from the {fourth order:title} tag (i.e.: Navajo, Navajo bench, Navajo meadow). Can you update the question with what's expected vs what you're getting?

Comment: @Romans-8---31-39 Its the right words but.. when it renders it loops at the first <li> tag jumps straight to {third order:exp:playa:children… and misses {summary_3rd_order} in-between and creating extra tab boxes (generating a whole bunch div's and li's that shouldn't be there). It should give a summary and the a list of names that fall playa list entries under it's parent name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was the final solution.

```
     {exp:playa:children field="3rd_order_under" sort="asc" var_prefix="thirdorder"}
     <li {if '{thirdorder:count}' == '1'}class="active"{/if} id="pillTab{thirdorder:url_title}Tab">
       <div class="row">                                     
         <div class="twelve columns"> 
           {thirdorder:summary_3rd_order}<br />

           {thirdorder:exp:playa:children field="4th_order_under_3rd_order" sort="asc" var_prefix="fourthorder" backspace="2"}
             {fourthorder:title}, {/thirdorder:exp:playa:children}

         </div>
       </div>
     </li>
    {/exp:playa:children}
```

Answer (score 1):

To try and get a handle on what's going on, I would break things down to just the variable output and forget about the html markup until it makes sense.  Try this and see if you can pinpoint it:

```
{exp:playa:children
    field="3rd_order_under" 
    sort="asc" 
    var_prefix="thirdorder"
}
    3rd count: {thirdorder:count} of {thirdorder:total_results}<br>
    3rd url_title: {thirdorder:url_title}<br>
    3rd summary_3rd_order: {thirdorder:summary_3rd_order}<br>

    {thirdorder:exp:playa:children 
        field="4th_order_under_3rd_order" 
        sort="asc" 
        var_prefix="fourthorder"
    }
        4th count: {fourthorder:count} of {fourthorder:total_results}<br>
        4th title: {fourthorder:title}<br>
        <hr>
    {/thirdorder:exp:playa:children}

    <hr>
{/exp:playa:children}
```

Comment: @Jeremy, Romans Thanks for all the input thus far! I am getting it to display the right stuff I just can't get it to interact with tabs correctly. Without the prefix code it works fine and I have provided links to two pages one with straight ahead EE code with out 4th_order_under_3rd_order. I also reworked the original question with code of where I am at now. Any further assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The inner `exp:playa:children` tag should not be prefixed. The var_prefix is for the variables inside the tag, not for other tags.

You'll want to do something like this:

```
{exp:playa:children
    field="3rd_order_under" 
    sort="asc" 
    var_prefix="thirdorder"
}
    3rd count: {thirdorder:count} of {thirdorder:total_results}<br>
    3rd url_title: {thirdorder:url_title}<br>
    3rd summary_3rd_order: {thirdorder:summary_3rd_order}<br>

    {exp:playa:children 
        field="4th_order_under_3rd_order" 
        sort="asc" 
        var_prefix="fourthorder"
        entry_id="{thirdorder:entry_id}"
    }
        4th count: {fourthorder:count} of {fourthorder:total_results}<br>
        4th title: {fourthorder:title}<br>
        <hr>
    {/exp:playa:children}

    <hr>
{/exp:playa:children}
```